# Flutter pass data to Statefulwidget

Tags: flutter, dart

I need to know how can i pass data through the screens

Here is how I am sending data.

```
 class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {

  @override
  initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState

    super.initState();
    doSomeAsyncStuff();
  }

  Future<List> doSomeAsyncStuff() async {
    final storage = new FlutterSecureStorage();
    String value = await storage.read(key: 'Cnic');
    print(value);

    String url = 'http://api.igiinsurance.com.pk:8888/insurance_IgiGen/insurance-api/get_company_employee.php?offset=0&limit=1&cnic=${value}' ;
    final msg = jsonEncode({"cnic": value});
    Map<String,String> headers = {'Content-Type':'application/json'};

    String token = value;
    final response = await http.get(url);

    var Data = json.decode(response.body);
    print(Data);

    var familyMembers = Data["records"][0]["family_members"];
    print(familyMembers);
    for (var familyMember in familyMembers){ //prints the name of each family member
      var familyMemberName = familyMember["name"];
      var familyMemberGender = familyMember["gender"];
      var familyMemberAge = familyMember["age"];
      var familyMemberRelationship = familyMember["relationship"];
      print(familyMemberName);
    }

  }
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double statusBarHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top;
    double width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    double height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;

   
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle: true,
        automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
        title: Text('IGI GENERAL INSURANCE'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: GestureDetector(
          onTap: (){
            Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => PersonalPage(familyMemberName, familyMemberGender)),
            );
          },
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              ClipRRect(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(35),
                  child: Image(
                    image: AssetImage("assets/images/reg.png"),
                    height: height * 0.1,
                  )),
              Text(
                'Personal',
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 17, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      )
    );
  }
}
```

This is how i am sending the values

```
onTap: (){
             Navigator.push(
                 context,
                 MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => PersonalPage(familyMemberName, 
                 familyMemberGender)),
                          );}
```

Now i want to show the value in a other stateful widget

```
class PersonalPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _PersonalPageState createState() => _PersonalPageState();
}

class _PersonalPageState extends State<PersonalPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Text('Show name here '),
          Text('Show gender here ')
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

As you can see i have values i am passing to the other stateful widget. I need to show the value now in Text Widget

Added _homeState also in a question now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can receive the values by using the constructor of the `PersonalPage` class:

```
import "package:flutter/material.dart";

class PersonalPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final List<String> names;
  final List<String> genders;
  PersonalPage(this.names,this.genders); 
  @override
  _PersonalPageState createState() => _PersonalPageState();
}

class _PersonalPageState extends State<PersonalPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: 
ListView.builder( //use ListView here to show all the names and genders
itemCount: widget.names.length,
itemBuilder: (BuildContext context,int index){
  return ListTile(
          title: Text(widget.names[index]),
          subtitle: Text(widget.genders[index])
        ],
      );
})
  );
  }
}
```

Your `_HomePageState` should look like this:

```
class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
 //define your variables here so they are accessible throughout your widget tree
  List<String> familyMemberName = [];
  List<String> familyMemberGender = [];
  List<String> familyMemberAge = [];
  List<String> familyMemberRelationship = [];
  @override
  initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState

    super.initState();
    doSomeAsyncStuff();
  }

  Future<List> doSomeAsyncStuff() async {
    final storage = new FlutterSecureStorage();
    String value = await storage.read(key: 'Cnic');
    print(value);

    String url = 'http://api.igiinsurance.com.pk:8888/insurance_IgiGen/insurance-api/get_company_employee.php?offset=0&limit=1&cnic=${value}' ;
    final msg = jsonEncode({"cnic": value});
    Map<String,String> headers = {'Content-Type':'application/json'};

    String token = value;
    final response = await http.get(url);

    var Data = json.decode(response.body);
    print(Data);

    var familyMembers = Data["records"][0]["family_members"];
    print(familyMembers);
    for (var familyMember in familyMembers){ //prints the name of each family member
      //assign the values here
      familyMemberName.add(familyMember["name"]);
      familyMemberGender.add(familyMember["gender"]);
      familyMemberAge.add(familyMember["age"]);
      familyMemberRelationship.add(familyMember["relationship"]);
    }

  }
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double statusBarHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top;
    double width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    double height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;

   
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle: true,
        automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
        title: Text('IGI GENERAL INSURANCE'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: GestureDetector(
          onTap: (){
           if(familyMemberName.isNotEmpty() && familyMemberGender.isNotEmpty()){
            //we pass the lists here
            Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => PersonalPage(familyMemberName, familyMemberGender)),
} 
//only navigate to the new page if the values of familyMemberName and familyMemberGender are retrieved from the function(because your function returns a future so it might take sometimes before the values are assigned)

            );
          },
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              ClipRRect(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(35),
                  child: Image(
                    image: AssetImage("assets/images/reg.png"),
                    height: height * 0.1,
                  )),
              Text(
                'Personal',
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 17, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      )
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: When i passing the value in a function like this PersonalPage(familyMemberName, familyMemberGender) its showing error in a value The getter 'familyMemberGender' isn't defined for the class '_HomePageState'

Comment: I cannot see any `_HomePageState` class in your question but you need to define `familyMemberName` and `familyMemberGender` outside the function and inside the `_HomePageState` class and just assign their value inside the function

Comment: The reason for the error is that the scope of the variables are inisde the function and they will be destroyed after the function finishes. That's why you need to define them inside the `_HomePageState` class so the values will be available when you call onTap function

Comment: I upaded my answer

Comment: its working but seems like its showing just a last array value but the data we have pass have 2 3 arrays

Comment: sorry I didn't see the for loop, I updated my code. you can choose which Item of the array should be passed to the new page

Comment: is it not possible to pass whole loop ? mean pass whole name and it will show all name in text widget. Need to show the all names in next page

Comment: Yes you can pass the list and specify which one to show on the other page

Comment: you can use the Listview builder to show all name in PersnolPage like this :   ListView.builder(
                          itemCount: names.length,
                          shrinkWrap: true,
                          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                            return ListTile(
                              title: Text(names[index]),
                              subtitle: Text(genders[index]),
                            );
                          }),

Comment: if i am removing the array number its showing error mean like this its working PersonalPage(familyMemberName[0], familyMemberGender[0])) but when I remove [0] its showing error  The argument type 'List<String>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'.

Comment: I updated `PersonalPage` code as well as @jivanpatel suggested. Please use that code which we receive 2 `List<String>` and we show all the names and genders by using a `ListView`